# npm ERR! Workspaces not supported for global packages

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

NPM was working fine until today and suddenly I am getting this error for any NPM command.

Even : `npm -v`

Produces the error : `npm ERR! Workspaces not supported for global packages`

It's always just worked for me in the past so I really don't know much about how it works so struggling to fix this.

As far as I know, I updated nothing so not sure why it would suddenly stop working.

Driving me mad as I cannot work on my projects using SASS

I tried uninstalling NODE.JS and reinstalling but no luck.

**VERSION INFO**
NODE v18.16.0
NPM v9.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Reinstall npm: Uninstall the current npm and download and install the latest version of npm.

Check environment variables: Make sure there are no abnormal paths related to npm set in the system's environment variables.

Delete residual folders: Manually delete the following folders (if they exist) to ensure complete removal:

C:\Users**\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users**\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
C:\Users**.npmrc (this file is likely the main issue)
C:\Program Files\nodejs (default installation path for Node.js)
** Replace ** with your computer username.

Reinstall Node.js: Download the latest version of the Node.js installer and install it using the default settings.

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?